# CodaSlider 1.1.1 Height issue

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have extracted the [CodaSlider 1.1.1](http://www.ndoherty.biz/demos/coda-slider/1.1.1/).

The slider height extends when there is more content but it doesn't get resized when there is less content. Is there any possibility to set height resize according to the content in codaslider 1.1.1 version?

Comment: The version 2.0 does that: see [this demo](http://www.ndoherty.biz/demos/coda-slider/2.0/#1) Can't you use this newer version ?

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question about 1.1.1 is no...  Unless you want to get into the js and modify it your self.  There doesn't appear to be any default plugin settings/callbacks for you to use or hook in to.